# Extending MessageBox as View - Ext JS 4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, view, extjs4, messagebox

I'm trying to extend a MessageBox within a view so I can reuse it throughout my application.

It seems that when I do so, I lose some of the default functionality that makes the messagebox useful (msg, button definitions, icon definitons, default drag constraints, etc).  Documentation is a little confusing as it seems configs should be defined within the show() function, and I'm unsure of how to set them within my view.

How can I truly extend a **messagebox** component as a view?

Basic MessageBox (what I want to create with my view):

```
Ext.Msg.show({
     title:'Error',
     msg: 'There was an error.',
     buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL,
     icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION
});
```

Renders:

[image: Normal Messagebox]

but when I show my view:

```
Ext.create('IOL.view.app.Message').show();
```

I basically end up with a vanilla Panel/Window component

```
Ext.define('IOL.view.app.Message', {

    extend : 'Ext.window.Window',

    config: {

    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },


    initComponent : function() {

        Ext.apply(this, {
            xtype: 'messagebox',
            width: 400,
            height: 200,
            title:'Error',
            html: 'There was an error.',
            buttons: [
                { text: 'Button 1' }
            ]

        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }// initComponent
});
```

Renders:

[image]

Comment: Do you need to change the functionality of the MessageBox, or do you just want a MessageBox with the same configs to be able to use in multiple places?

Comment: Same functionality, just want to be able to define configs and create a view, sounds silly but doing so will allow me to do things such as call a xhr to log when app calls a messagebox for a returned error for example.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are extending an `Ext.window.Window` and applying the messagebox configs to it. Why not just extend `Ext.window.MessageBox`:

```
Ext.define('IOL.view.app.Message', {
    extend : 'Ext.window.MessageBox',
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    title: 'Error',
    html: 'There was an error.',
    buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL,
    icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR,

    // whatever else you want to do
    initComponent : function() {

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

@EricCook brings up a good point below. The `MessageBox` class is designed for reuse in the app as a singleton not really for subclassing.

In your question you said:

> I'm trying to extend a MessageBox within a view so I can reuse it
>   throughout my application

I can understand that if you want to create a different *type* of messagebox that you would call with the normal `Ext.Msg.show` method, you could extend the `MessageBox` with your own buttons or icons I suppose.

But for regular use this isn't something you need to extend. For repeated use in your app you could hold a reference to the message box config you want in the controller like:

```
// SomeController.js
errorMsg: {
     title:'Error',
     msg: 'There was an error.',
     buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL,
     icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION
},
```

Then whenever you want to call that type of message you could use (assuming the scope is the controller itself, or you could get a reference to the controller beforehand):

```
Ext.Msg.show(this.errorMsg);
```

Comment: `Ext.window.MessageBox` is a strange class. It is defined as a normal class, but it has a post-define function to make a singleton. It might be better to define this class as a singleton with an alternate class name, to make the calling syntax simpler. `IOL.Msg.show` is way easier to use than `Ext.create("IOL.view.app.Message").show`.

Comment: @Eric Cook, I like that, I'll give it a shot.  @Geronimo, If you extend `Ext.window.MessageBox` you get unexpected results, and an Uncaught TypeError due to that fact that I think the type of `MessageBox` needs to be somehow defined (prompt, alert) before extending it.

Comment: @Geronimo do you intend to say `buttons: buttons:` in your first code section? A suggested edit corrected this, but was rejected.